# php контент после /

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы после / выводилась страница пользователя. Не знаю как более правильнее описать. К примеру, в том же ВК. https://vk.com/user_url -  выводится страница пользователя. Как это называется и как работает в php?

Comment: Это делается с помощью файлов .ht_access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настраиваешь .htaccess файл чтобы все запросы через URL вернул на главную, то есть на index.

Тебе понадобиться глобальный массив $_SERVER с индексом REQUEST_URI.

Вписанный в index файл к примеру такой код даст тебе значения с URL после каждого слэша:

```
$url = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $page = $url[1];
   $page2 = $url[2];
   $page3 = $url[3];
```

В `body` ты с помощью функции `include` вставляешь нужные файлы. По такой системе у тебя `head` и `footer` остаются постоянными, а меняется только `body`

К примеру в твоей случае:

```
if($page == 'user') include "user.php";
```

URL будет выглядеть так: www.example.com/user

Далее в файле `user.php` прописываешь код чтобы выводить определенные данные пользователя по GET запросу, то есть уже `$page` есть, теперь через `$page2`.
Обычно используется `id`:

```
www.example.com/user/3
```

По `$page2` получаешь цифру, то есть `id` и по нему выводишь данные через базу.
Ты можешь создать отдельное поле в базе для уникального URL названия страницы и по нему вывести данные каждого пользователя.

```
www.example.com/user/username
```

Надеюсь смог помочь. Если есть вопросы задашь, отвечу.

Answer (score 3):

ЧПУ ссылки это. Нужна единая точка входа, и роутер URL
Например этот https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute